# Changed password for user, will ssh still work?

Tags: ssh

I changed the password for a user, but if someone still has the SSH key on their laptop the user can still login right?

The password is only used if you don't have a SSH key right?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, the user still is able to login only using the keys.

If you setup a SSH key for one of your clients then the preferred options for that client is to use SSH key unless he specifically uses the password authentication method like:

```
ssh -o PreferredAuthentications=password  host
```

then he should know the password. If you are looking for a way so no one can login to this account you have to remove the keys:

```
mv /home/user/.ssh/authorized_keys{,.rm}
```

then peoply only can login using password, but they still are able to copy their keys to `~/.ssh`.

for more flexible rules you have to changes your ssh server configs.